# Upper Bound for Difficulty of Questions on Math.SE

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know that there has been previous discussion about the inappropriateness of certain questions for mathoverflow.net, such as questions pertaining to elementary notions of compactness or differentiability.  So, in a sense, there is an established lower bound for the difficulty of questions for mathoverflow.net, but is there an established upper bound for the difficulty of questions for math.se?  Certainly, this is de facto the case, but is there a level of question which would be inappropriate for math.se based on the high level of difficulty or sophistication of the question? If there is not, should there be? It seems that it would be detrimental for certain high level problems to be posted on the site, and certainly not beneficial to the majority of users of math.se.

Comment: Somewhat related question, on future potential migration of some questions to MathOverflow: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0

Comment: There is also an upper bound on MO. MO is not for known open problems.

Comment: 9${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 23):

All mathematics problems are welcome here.  There is no upper or lower bound for what level question may be asked, and I do not see why more advanced mathematics would be "detrimental" to the majority of users.

In some cases, after receiving no answers, some users have then posted their question on math overflow.  In some rare cases where a questions was posted on both sites, the answer has actually appeared on math stack exchange rather than overflow.

Comment: Let me add a small comment to this: we do _not_ discourage hard problems from being posted here. But we _recognize_ that for questions related to current research, it is likely you will get quicker and more complete answers over at MathOverflow. And it is not just research mathematics. In the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) we describe several cases where your questions _would be on topic here_ but may still receive faster and better responses elsewhere.

Comment: Also "better response" is subjective here.  It is possible that the same question would get a better answer *for that asker* here or at MO for different askers.

Comment: "All mathematics problems are welcome here." 

From my experience, I really doubt that.